# Java CompletableFuture: Trying to run two void methods as CompletableFuture and block until both complete

Tags: java, completable-future

I am trying to run two void method1 and method2 async and then block the code until both methods are done.

Does this achieve that?

```
      CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> method1());
      CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> method2());
      CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).join();
```

Comment: Yes. Did you try running it?

Answer (score 1):

I think code `CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).join();` should work fine. Could you try this, did you have any problems?

Or you can use something like:

```
  Arrays.asList(future1,future1).forEach(Future::get);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the dedicated method `runAsync` though?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> method1());
      CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> method2());

      CompletableFuture<Void> compound = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2);
      compound.join();
      System.out.println("compound done");
}
```

And yes, your `compound` will be "joined" on the other thread (`main` in the example above), as such that `compound done` message will be printed only after both methods executed.